# Do harbour cranes lay dormant?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

I am trying to construct 'alternate text' for a photograph I am submitting for evaluation. The photo is in the 'cityscape' category and depicts the harbour at dawn with cranes that are normally busy - but not are still in the early morn.

The phrase that came to mind was

> The Harbour Cranes lay dormant at sunrise in the Townsville Port. '

However, I'm unsure as to whether the 'lay dormant' phrase is correct. It elicits a sense of non movement over am extended period of time whereas I'm trying to express a sense of rest and impending awakening.

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dormant` as in `temporarily inactive`, works. However, `lay` is past tense.  Consider `lie` dormant for present tense and your "sense of [...] impending awakening".  Present tense puts you in the moment.  Past tense implies that the moment is over and nothing is impending except maybe more historical revelations.

http://web.ku.edu/~edit/lie.html

http://absolutewrite.com/forums/showthread.php?105210-The-Definitive-Lay-or-Lie-Thread

Comment: Ah thank you ... wasn't seeing that and such a simple adjustment... knew it didn't feel correct but could not see the wood for the trees... too embedded in the visual to notice the written... a significant departure for me, the learning curve of which I guess imposes... will make requisite adjustments based on your advice. Am most grateful thanks.

Comment: @drcrpsych  I'm impressed that you went so far to ask.  Shows attention to detail.  That's when prose approaches poetry.  You've certainly made me want a look at this picture.